# How to run ros::spin in the background

Tags: ros, boost, multi-thread, spin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a qt application and which has many Callbacks. As I dont have and infinite loop, I can't write ros::spin(). I would like to have ros::spin() or spinonce() in the background. How can i achieve using multi-threading.  Any help would be highly appreciated

Thanks,
Arjun

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210231/how-to-run-ros::spin-in-the-background/) by [arjunsurendrans](https://answers.ros.org/users/22602/arjunsurendrans/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-05-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS, `spin()` and multi-threading has been asked a few times already. Some earlier questions & answers:

- [ROS callbacks, threads and spinning](http://answers.ros.org/question/53055/ros-callbacks-threads-and-spinning/)
- [Multi-threading in ROS nodes and MultiThreadedSpinner and AsyncSpinner](http://answers.ros.org/question/116791/multi-threading-in-ros-nodes-and-multithreadedspinner-and-asyncspinner/)
- [Multiple Threads in Single ROS Node](http://answers.ros.org/question/10328/multiple-threads-in-single-ros-node/)

And just for completeness, the authoritative source [roscpp/Overview/Callbacks and Spinning](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning).

In your case an `AsyncSpinner` is probably a good option (from [roscpp/Overview/Callbacks and Spinning - Multi-threaded Spinning](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning#Multi-threaded_Spinning)):

```
ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(4); // Use 4 threads
spinner.start();
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arjunsurendrans](https://answers.ros.org/users/22602/arjunsurendrans/) on 2015-06-01**:
Thank you for your quick reply

**Comment by [zzzZuo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25453/zzzzuo/) on 2015-12-30**:
I read these links, and I do it in the same way,but it doesn't work in my pro.
1.I run spin() in boost::thread,and subscribe in Goal::Goal()(ie:    ros::Subscriber sub = nh_.subscribe<actionlib_msgs::GoalStatusArray>("/move_base/status",100,fun_cb);)
but the thread also block my GUI.Thanks your help